# How do I query a complex key in pouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

If I was to make a get request, I'd do something like:

> https://myserver.com/sometestdb/_design/sortJob/_view/index?limit=100&reduce=false&**startkey=["job_price"]&endkey=["job_price", {}]**

For a map query like:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.data.type === "job") {
        emit(["job_ref", doc.data.ref], null);
        emit(["job_price", doc.data.price], null);
    }
}
```

How would I replicate the query using pouchDb [query](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database)? I've tried a few things around the start and end keys but no luck:

```
{
  include_docs: true,
  startkey: 'job_price',
  endkey: 'job_price,{}'
}

{
  include_docs: true,
  startkey: 'job_price',
  endkey: 'job_price\uffff'
}
```

Both of these return 0 results whereas the link I use produces the expected results.

Note: I can confirm the data is present in my pouchDB as I've queried it using the `pouch-find` plugin but am trying various techniques to see which is faster.

EDIT: According to the [complex keys section](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) in the docs, I should be able to do the following:

```
{
  include_docs: true,
  startkey: '[\'job_price\']',
  endkey: '[\'job_price\',{}]'
}
```

But that results in:

> No rows can match your key range, reverse your start_key and end_key
>   or set {descending : true}

But I should be able to get results like this and don't want `descending: true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so it was my reading of the documentation that was off.

When building the start / end key, you need to pass the array, not pass the array as a string (which I thought pouchDB then `eval`'d.

This is the working query:

```
{
  include_docs: true,
  startkey: ['job_price'],
  endkey: ['job_price', {}]
}
```

Posting this answer rather than deleting the question as it might help someone else.